# Bootstrap modal wizard with coldfusion, issue displaying out on data-step="2" from input in data-step="1"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap to create a pop up windows which will have a wizard, when you click on the button "Launch demo modal" it will give you the pop up windows to select the date and then you will click next, on the next page in the same windows I would like to somehow display the results from the selection from the first window, see below for what I am looking to do, certain tags might be out of place but this should give you an idea. If anymore has experience or have an alternate way of doing this , input is apprecicated.

One question I have is how do I make the "next button" save the selection from the calendar which I can then cfoutput out to the next step.

Launch demo modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="js-title-step"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row hide" data-step="1" data-title="Please select the date!">
            <div class="well">
  <b>Please select a date on the calendar and click Next.</b><br>
  <br>
  <cfform>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><strong>Start Date</strong>:</td>
          <td><cfinput type="datefield"  name="dte_one" size="10" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </cfform>
    </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row hide" data-step="2" data-title="This is the second and last step!">
            <div class="well">
               <h3 style="color:OrangeRed;"> 
                    Your Joining date is: <cfoutput>#DateFormat(Form.dte_one)# </cfoutput>
             </h3>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-btn-step pull-left" data-orientation="cancel" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning js-btn-step" data-orientation="previous"></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success js-btn-step" data-orientation="next"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You may wan to split up the forms into separate pages. I would be tempted to AJAX in the content and have it replace the content in the modal. The runner up approach would be to use an `<iframe>` in the modal. To implement what you are doing above, would be client side only. It would require using javascript only. `form.dte_one` does not exist until after submitting

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to activate modal in CF, I add 2 # in href which is what you could try with button.

```
<a href="##?URL=#Name#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##ModalID">#DataName#</a>
```